# Algorithm to Sort Many Arrays with Potentially Similar Features

Tags: algorithm, sorting

In usual circumstances, sorting arrays of ~1000s of simple items like integer or floats is sufficiently fast that the small differences between implementations just doesn't matter.

But what if you need to sort N modest sized arrays that have been generated by some similar process or simply have have some relatedness?

I leave the specifics of what of the mysterious array generator and relationships of the generated arrays intentionally vague. It is up to any applicable algorithms to specify a large as possible domain where they will work when they will be most useful.

EDIT: Let's narrow this by letting the arrays be independent samples. There exists an unchanging probability distribution of arrays that will be generated. Implicitly then there's a stable probability distribution of elements in the arrays but it's conditonal -- the elements within an array might not be independent. It seems like it'd be extremely hard to make use of relationships between elements within the arrays but I could be wrong. We can narrow further if needed by letting the elements in the arrays be independent. In that case the problem is to effectively learn and use the probability distribution of elements in the arrays.

Comment: "some relatedness" is pretty vague. The same items in different orders is related, but it's unlikely you could use that information to derive a better sorting technique. If they're different items but "approximately in the same order", then you *might* get an improvement by sorting one of the arrays, using the same swaps on the others, and then following up with an insertion sort to resolve the (assumed) small number of remaining inversions. That's just two examples. Without more information about your "relatedness", it's impossible to answer this question.

Comment: I like the insertion sort idea. These are the clever ideas I wanted to hear about but I wasn't quite sure how to define "some relatedness".

Comment: I fear that writing and debugging any "clever relatedness-using" algorithm will be costlier than just sorting each and be done. Or you might essentially use one of the arrays as "keys" and the others as "data," and do as @JimMischel suggests...

Comment: If you do find a series of swaps that will tend to give you a nearly sorted array is there a way to simplify that series of swaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a paper on a [self improving sorting algorithm](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~chazelle/pubs/soda06.pdf).  I am pretty strong with algorithms and machine learning, but this paper is definitely not an easy read for me.

The abstract says this

> We investigate ways in which an algorithm can improve
>   its expected performance by fine-tuning itself automatically with respect to an arbitrary, unknown input distribution. We give such self-improving algorithms for
>   sorting and clustering. The highlights of this work: 
>   a sorting algorithm with optimal expected limiting running time ...
>   In all cases, the algorithm begins with a learning phase
>   during which it adjusts itself to the input distribution
>   (typically in a logarithmic number of rounds), followed
>   by a stationary regime in which the algorithm settles to
>   its optimized incarnation.